# Bash script failing but part running

Tags: bash, shell

Can anyone see anything wrong with the following?

I have been looking over and over and can't see the issue, but its failing to create the SQL dump and no tar is being created.

The variables would have their details obviously. I have checked these are all correct.

```
#!/bin/bash

SITE=""
PATH=""
SERVER=""
DBUSER=""
DB=""
DBPW=""

DATE=`date '+%d-%m-%y-%H-%M'`

tar -czf ~/backup/${DATE}-${SITE}.tar.gz \
  /var/sites/${PATH}/public_html

mysqldump -f \
  -u ${DBUSER} ${DB} \
  -p${DBPW} \
  -h ${SERVER} > ~/backup/${DATE}-db-${SITE}.sql

find ~/backup -mtime +3 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

The purpose of the code is to create the backup of my server files and database. The script is running via CRON.

Comment: Do you have spaces in any of your variables? If so, you may want to surround that part of the command with double quotes

Comment: Also, is the user that cron is using to execute the script a factor?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.Brink. I don't have any spaces in the variables.

Comment: PATH is an important environment variable. I recommend to use lower case letters for your own variables.

Comment: Read [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667) -- you'll want to quote all your variables, particularly the password as it's the most likely to have globbing wildcards

Comment: As @Cyrus implies, when you say `PATH=""` you tell the shell to forget where to find `tar`, `mysqldump` and `find`.  Nothing will work.  But you imply that your real script actually has values assigned to these variables.  You will need to provide a little more detail.

Comment: The problem is that you are blowing out your environments PATH variable. This holds the path of executables in your system so you can type `mysqldump` and it will know where to find that program. You set it in this script and so `mysqldump` will never run because your system has no idea where to find it.

Comment: @glennjackman Thank you, I'll take a read of that. Do you mean something like "$password" ?

Comment: Exactly: `mysqldump -f -u "$user" -p"$pass" -h "$server" > ~/backup/"$date-db-$site".sql` -- even if you know the variable does not contain spaces or globbing characters (such as your date), it's a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of places in your script that will have a hard time handling spaces. There are also some other improvements that can help you fix the problem (since you didn't give us any failing output...).

General

- Used `"` around parameters for commands where you can end up having spaces.
- Put `set -x` on the top of your script to see what is happening when it runs. This can also be triggered running it using `bash -x script.sh`.
- Use `set -u` on top to let the script die when there is a undefined variable.
- Use `set -e` on top to let it die if a command fails.
- Use `set -eu` to combine them both :)
- If your find supports it, use its `-delete`, instead of `-exec rm -f {} \;`. If it doesn't, make sure you wrap it in `"`, or better, use `-print0` and `xargs` with `-0` input. Depending on the versions you have, the idea is to use `NUL` as a separator, instead of whitespaces (default shell).